# ERROR: Could not build wheels for onnx, pycocotools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, deep-learning, yolo

was trying to install yolox
pip install -r requirements.txt and got this

Using legacy 'setup.py install' for onnx-simplifier, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Building wheels for collected packages: onnx, pycocotools
Building wheel for onnx (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for onnx (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [82 lines of output]
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:757: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'license-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'license_file' instead
warnings.warn(
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
running create_version
running cmake_build
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (project):
Generator

```
      NMake Makefiles

    does not support platform specification, but platform

      x64

    was specified.


  CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-9m548hbh/onnx_ad97fc2a0af84a5fa92a29cfbc51c296/.setuptools-cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 244, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 229, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 281, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 174, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 321, in <module>
      setuptools.setup(
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "setup.py", line 217, in run
      self.run_command('cmake_build')
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-du9u4xrx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "setup.py", line 203, in run
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_args)
    File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\ASUS\\anaconda3\\envs\\myenv\\Library\\bin\\cmake.exe', '-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=c:\\users\\asus\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\include', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\asus\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe', '-DBUILD_ONNX_PYTHON=ON', '-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON', '-DONNX_NAMESPACE=onnx', '-DPY_EXT_SUFFIX=.cp39-win_amd64.pyd', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DPY_VERSION=3.9', '-DONNX_USE_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON', '-A', 'x64', '-T', 'host=x64', '-DONNX_ML=1', 'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9m548hbh\\onnx_ad97fc2a0af84a5fa92a29cfbc51c296']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for onnx
Building wheel for pycocotools (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for pycocotools (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [14 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycocotools
copying pycocotools\coco.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycocotools
copying pycocotools\cocoeval.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycocotools
copying pycocotools\mask.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycocotools
copying pycocotools_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycocotools
running build_ext
skipping 'pycocotools_mask.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycocotools
Failed to build onnx pycocotools
ERROR: Could not build wheels for onnx, pycocotools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

(myenv) C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\YOLOX-main>

Answer (score -1):

> since package 'wheel' is not installed

install wheel:
pip3 install wheel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Conda environment you can run this commmand

conda install -c conda-forge pycocotools